# Flutter application fails to send the data - there is not enough time

Tags: flutter, http, backup

The application is used to measure steps, and the goal is that if it accidentally shuts down, before that it sends a request to the server to save the number of steps.

The application fails to send data to the server due to the shutdown of the application, how can I solve it?

The app doesn't seem to have time for that.

```
case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        var steps =
            Provider.of<StepsProvider>(context, listen: false).getTotalSteps;
        if (steps != '0') {
          //Yup, the code works here, but don't have time to send requests to the server or save local storage data.
          await StepsBackUp(steps: steps).saveBackUpSteps(); // same for local storage
          await PedometerService(steps: steps).saveRecord();
        }
        break;
```